# jQuery value returned from text() causes unrecognised expression error when adding to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;

    // Empty aarray to store list of headings
    var tableHeadings = [];

    // For each heading present add it to the array (ordered)
    $('#AdvancedTable thead > tr > th').each(function () {
        //console.log($(this).text());
        $(tableHeadings).add($(this).text());
    });

    // For each row in the table, add the heading text to the start of each cell
    $('#AdvancedTable tbody > tr > td').each(function (index) {
        $(this).prepend('<span class="visible-xs">' + tableHeadings[index] + '</span>');
    })

});
```

However, one of my table headings I am storing values from contains the text "Length (L1)". I get the following error in my console:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, recognised expression: Length (L1)

I understand the basics that this is caused by there being issues with text passing something with brackets in it, but would like to know the details of why this happens and a hint as to how I can solve this/best practices to avoid an error like this.

Comment: Why do you wrap the array in an jQuery object? For every table header column?
 O.o

Comment: @Andreas I was already using jQuery and saw an add method for arrays. Didn't see any harm in using it, could anyone explain why that results in an error?

Comment: jQuery `add` is not the same as `Array.push`. https://api.jquery.com/add/

Comment: @BrahmaDev so mine was creating a jQuery object?

Comment: It was very likely not doing anything unless the values of `$(this).text()` were also valid as a selector expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `each`.

```js
// Empty aarray to store list of headings
    var tableHeadings = $('#AdvancedTable thead > tr > th').map(function () {
      return this.innerHTML;
    }).get();
```

You are creating an empty array, iterating over elements, and adding them to an array.  This is essentially reinventing the wheel for what map already does.

Comment: like it is elegant +1

Comment: @Taplar Had a look at various pages for documentation on get, all of them seem to say that get has a required key parameter? Is there a reason why this isn't present in your snippet? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: `get()` can take a position if you want to return just one.  Otherwise if you call just get() it will return the entire results as a plain array.

Comment: This is ES6 right? I can't use ES6 in this project if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

tableHeadings is a simple array, so you can use push function to add value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    let tableHeadings = [];

    $('#AdvancedTable thead > tr > th').each( (index, item) => {
       tableHeadings.push($(item).text())
    });

    $('#AdvancedTable tbody > tr > td').each( (index, item) => {
        $(item).prepend('<span class="visible-xs">' + tableHeadings[index] + '</span>');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using JQuery to add an item to a list; perhaps try:

```
tableHeadings.push($(this).text());
```

instead of the original line:

```
$(tableHeadings).add($(this).text());
```

Comment: this.innerHTML would also avoid another jQuery wrapping

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(tableHeadings).add($(this).text());
```

need to be 
`tableHeadings.push($(this).text())`